# Riemann upper sum of Riemann integral

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I read this lecture note [https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125b/ch1.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/m125b/ch1.pdf). For all partitions $P$ of finite closed interval $[a,b]$, define the upper Riemann sum $f$ w.r.t. partition $P$ by $U(f; P)$. If $f$ is bounded, then $m(b-a)\leq U(f; P)$, where $m\leq f.$

> why $\inf_{P} U(f; P)$ exists? We do not need to claim $U(f; P)$ is decreasing?
>
> And how about the $\lim_{P} U(f; P)$? Here is the limit of the net.

Comment: No, it doesn't even make sense to say "decreasing" here. All you need is *some* lower bound, which you obviously have.

Comment: Do not we use the monotone convergence theorem? Why only have the lower bound?

Comment: $\lim_P$ makes no sense. Where are you getting this?

Comment: @TedShifrin The question asks to show that the net $\{U(f; P)\}$ converges. So how to deal with that? And what is the limit?

Comment: @TedShifrin By the monotone convergence theorem, since the net $U(f; P)$ is decreasing and bounded below by $m(b-a)$. So the net converges?

Comment: It will converge to the inf. You need to work with definitions ... I don't do nets.

Comment: What do you mean "work with f'?

Comment: @TedShifrin I know the definitions. But I want to deal with the nets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection of partitions $\mathcal{P}$ is directed set with preorder $\supseteq$ where $P' \supseteq P$ indicates that $P'$ is a refinement of $P$, that is the set of endpoints of subintervals of $P$ is contained in the set of endpoints of subintervals  of $P'$.

The net $\{U(f;P) \}$ defined on $\mathcal{P}$ is non-increasing in the sense that $P' \supseteq P$ implies that $U(P';f) \leqslant U(P;f)$.  In other words, upper Darboux sums decrease as partitions are refined.

Since the net $\{U(f;P) \}$  is bounded below and non-increasing  it is convergent.

Comment: For your final claim, we do not prove it? Same as the sequence?

Comment: @TYG: Yes -- it is similar to a sequence. The sums that form the net are bounded below and there exists $U(f) = \inf_{P \in \mathcal{P}} U(P;f)$. By properties of the infimum, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $P_\epsilon$ such that $U(f) \leqslant U(P_{\epsilon};f) < U(f) + \epsilon$. We have monotonicity such that for any partition $P$, if $P \supseteq P_\epsilon$ then $U(P;f) \leqslant U(P_\epsilon;f)$. Thus $U(f) \leqslant U(P;f) < U(f) + \epsilon$ for all such $P$.